# calling javascript from flash menu not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome

I have a flash menu where i call some javascript functions

```
 javascript:hideTopMenu();
```

this function is working for firefox and safari 
but not working for IE and chrome
any suggestions please
 ?

Comment: How do you call that in flash? It should probably be `ExternalInterface.call("hideTopMenu");`

Comment: to be clear , i dont know how the flash menu is written , but i have fields where i can put the java function , and when compiled , this function will be executed

Comment: Need to see more code, `javascript:hideTopMenu();` does not make any sense to me here, sorry.

Comment: let me make it more easy, can i from a flash menu call a pop up with a dark background ?

Comment: Do you mean that the function is being called but you have a css problem? Have you verified that `hideTopMenu` is being called in chrome? You can verify that by placing an `alert` inside `hideTopMenu` for example.

Comment: yeah , hideTopMenu is working fine for safari and firefox , so the problem is not with the function, my problem is how to call this function from a flash menu